# String '04/28/2021 04:25p' was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, .net-core

I'm getting data from a third-party API. I'm receiving a date string like this `"04/28/2021 04:25p"`. Can't convert this string into a DateTime value.

I've tried the following:

```
var dateValue = DateTime.ParseExact(
    "04/28/2021 04:25p", 
    "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm tt", 
    new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

What is it I'm missing here?

Update: I've used double quotes in my code, forgot to put double-quote here. Updated the question now.

Comment: Perhaps double-quotes around the string?

Comment: "tt" is when you expect  "AM/PM" in the string, what is "p" and why is it attached to the minute value?

Comment: do you have `p` suffix int the `04/28/2021 04:25p` or `pm`?

Comment: AFAIK `PM` is a valid [AM/PM designator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#ttSpecifier)  for en-US. Also you don't have a blank beteween time and designator in your string (and you do in your format).

Comment: `What is it I'm missing here?` - my guess would be an `m`

Comment: You use `HH` which is **24** hour format (hour is in `0..23` range). Is it correct? Typically we put `hh` - `12` hour format with `AM/PM`

Comment: @Steve - yes I'm receiving the string exactly like that, a 'p' attached to the minute value, that's what confuses me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a single letter AM/PM-designator, but then it has to be uppercase:

```cs
var dateValue = DateTime.ParseExact(
    "04/28/2021 04:25p".ToUpper(), 
    "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mmt", 
    new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Otherwise you need to add the 'm':

```cs
var dateValue = DateTime.ParseExact(
    "04/28/2021 04:25p"+"m", 
    "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mmtt", 
    new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

The third option is to code your own CultureInfo, where DateTimeFormat.AMDesignator is 'm' and DateTimeFormat.PMDesignator is 'p':

```cs
public class SingleLetterDesignatorCultureInfo : CultureInfo
{
    private DateTimeFormatInfo dateTimeFormatInfo;
    
    public SingleLetterDesignatorCultureInfo():base(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Name)
    {
        dateTimeFormatInfo = base.DateTimeFormat;
        dateTimeFormatInfo.PMDesignator = "p";
        dateTimeFormatInfo.AMDesignator = "a";
    }
        
    public override DateTimeFormatInfo DateTimeFormat 
    {
        get => dateTimeFormatInfo;
        set => base.DateTimeFormat = value;
    }
}

var dateValue = DateTime.ParseExact(
    "04/28/2021 04:25p", 
    "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mmtt", 
    new SingleLetterDesignatorCultureInfo());
```

Comment: Thanks, @Palle, the third option suits the best for me.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, use double-quotes.
Secondly, you can stick an "m" at the end of the input to help with the formatting.

```
string inputPlusM = "04/28/2021 04:25p" + "m";
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(inputPlusM, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mmtt", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US") );
```